# SQL-Sever table does not update after insert

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Currently I'm learning Java JDBC with MSSQL database. And I cannot insert data into Stats table with the code below although all steps finish successfully.

The code is: getting data from Entity table, stored it into a Collection. Finally feeding data from that collection into `Stats` table.

The code `insertCommand.executeUpdate()` return 1, but the table `Stats` does not contain any data that the code try to insert.

Why does this happen?

```
protected void FillStats(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement selectCmd = DatabaseHelper.createCommand(connection,
            "Select Id, Created, CreatedBy, Updated, UpdatedBy from Entity");
    System.out.println("A SQL statement has been created to retrieving data from Entity table.");
    List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    try (ResultSet results = selectCmd.executeQuery()) {
        int numberOfObject = 0;
        System.out.println(">>> Start getting data from Entity table.");
        while (results.next()) {
            list.add(new Object[] { results.getInt(1), results.getDate(2), results.getString(3), results.getDate(4),
                    results.getString(5) });
            ++numberOfObject;
        }
        System.out.println("Total number of records retrieved: " + numberOfObject);
    }

    for (Object[] media : list) {
        PreparedStatement insertCmd = DatabaseHelper.createCommand(connection,
                "Insert into Stats ([Id], [Created], [CreatedBy], [Updated], [UpdatedBy]) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        insertCmd.setInt(1, (int) media[0]);
        insertCmd.setDate(2, (Date) media[1]);
        insertCmd.setString(3, (String) media[2]);
        insertCmd.setDate(4, (Date) media[3]);
        insertCmd.setString(5, (String) media[4]);

        int updated = insertCmd.executeUpdate();
        if (updated > 0) {
            System.out.println("success");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Stuck somewhere");
        }
    }
}
```

Table Stats create command:

```
createCommand(con, "create table Stats "
            + "(Id INT not null, "
            + "Created DATETIME not null, "
            + "CreatedBy NVARCHAR(255) not null, "
            + "Updated DATETIME null, "
            + "UpdatedBy NVARCHAR(255) null, "
            + "primary key (Id))").execute()
```

Table Entity:

```
CREATE TABLE [Entity](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Version] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Properties] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [TypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TypeVersionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Updated] [datetime] NULL,
    [UpdatedBy] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY 
(
    [Id] ASC
))
```

Comment: You don't show the calling code, but most likely you don't call commit on the connection, so the changes are rolled back.

Comment: That’s the point!! Accidentally i call method setAutoCommit(false) at the beginning of everything. Now it’s work well!!

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into the document of MySQL and as i see you can't give the column name in square brackets. You need to write the query as

```
Insert into TableName (column1 , column2 , column3) values (value1 , value2 , value3);
```

As you are using the same number of values as number of columns you can directly values as

```
Insert into TableName values (your values);
```

Comment: The OP is using SQL Server, not MySQL. In SQL Server the square brackets can be used to quote object names (similar to using double quotes in standard SQL, or backticks in MySQL).

Answer (score 0):

I found somethings, that might help. You have declared Created and Updated as DATETIME, this requires Timestamp not Date.
Also you create the PreparedStatement for the insert command on every loop, try it before the loop. I also recommend to close the DB-objects before exiting. So I have successfully tried it with  this code:

```
protected void FillStats(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement selectCmd = connection.prepareStatement("Select Id, Created, CreatedBy, Updated, UpdatedBy from Entity");

    System.out.println("A SQL statement has been created to retrieving data from Entity table.");
    List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    try (ResultSet results = selectCmd.executeQuery()) {
        int numberOfObject = 0;
        System.out.println(">>> Start getting data from Entity table.");
        while (results.next()) {
            list.add(new Object[]{results.getInt(1), results.getTimestamp(2), results.getString(3), results.getTimestamp(4),
                results.getString(5)});
            ++numberOfObject;
        }
        System.out.println("Total number of records retrieved: " + numberOfObject);
        results.close();
        selectCmd.close();
    }

    PreparedStatement insertCmd = connection.prepareStatement("Insert into Stats ([Id], [Created], [CreatedBy], [Updated], [UpdatedBy]) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    for (Object[] media : list) {

        insertCmd.setInt(1, (int) media[0]);
        insertCmd.setTimestamp(2, (Timestamp) media[1]);
        insertCmd.setString(3, (String) media[2]);
        insertCmd.setTimestamp(4, (Timestamp) media[3]);
        insertCmd.setString(5, (String) media[4]);

        int updated = insertCmd.executeUpdate();
        if (updated > 0) {
            System.out.println("success");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Stuck somewhere");
        }
    }
    insertCmd.close();
}
```